# iOS Trying to figure out nasty crash

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault

Normally the crash log indicates where this might be happening, but in this case, this is all I am getting.  Lets say my main view is A and I have A,B, and C views.

This only happens if I do the following:

Go from A to B to C, go out of app and load up a few other apps.  Then return to my app, go back to B, then go back to A (THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES).

EDIT - I had posted the wrong thread before...here is the correct thread

CRASH LOG:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4daf03bd
Crashed Thread:  7

Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x36f22f78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x33707d04 _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x34f3a96e __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 7998
3   CoreFoundation                  0x34eb51d8 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 68
4   Foundation                      0x33707c2e +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 54
5   MyGreatApp                      0x00061028 -[DataAccessor getProducts:div:productType:cat:searchsilver:completion:] (DataAccessor.m:301)
6   MyGreatApp                      0x00017196 __36-[products showNationalCategories]_block_invoke_0 (products.m:1688)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x37886c52 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x378927b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 256
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35b45df4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35b45cc8 start_wqthread + 0
```

Here is line 301 (Note, all the objects going into the string are NSStrings):

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?api_key=%@&device[duid]=%@&division=%@",apiUrl,apiKey, duid, division];
```

Comment: Something to do with a bad `UIImage` instance, but hard to tell unless you post some code...

Comment: Fire up gdb, show us what the parameters of memcpy are.

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess and say that source or dest on your image is NULL, or perhaps you are attempting to copy 0xFFFFFFFF bytes.

Comment: I put my money on you copying some code to customize the back button in a fancy non standard way.

Comment: In my OP I had accidentally pasted thread 0, which is totally not the offending thread..I corrected it now.  I see where it is pointing, but don't know why it is complaining

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that something is being deallocated in viewDidUnload which is relied upon and not being re-initialized properly. In most cases, viewDidUnload does not get called while testing; and it's the one thing I can think might be happening while you are off in those other apps. Do some double-checking on all of A's properties which get used when the view comes on screen, and double-check that they are non-nil.

Answer (score 0):

I think your callback is being run when a different view controller from the one you were expecting is being presented.  I think its first best to work out the faulty string pointer by NSLogging them on separate code lines.  Also have you used any _block decorations for those string parameters (or used them twice: both inside and outside the block) -- that would break the retain on them.